# Zend Framework CSV download

Tags: php, download, zend-framework2, export-to-csv

I am currently working on a CSV generator in Zend Framwork. At this point I am able to create a valid CSV file on the server side and now I want to download that file. I am currently using the following code:

```
$reader = new \PHPExcel_Reader_CSV();
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);

$excel = $reader->load($file); //$file = Path of the csv file in the local storage

$writer = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'CSV');

$path = 'public/download';
$fileName = 'test.csv';

$writer->save($path . '/' . $fileName);

$response = new ResponseStream();
$response->setStream(fopen($path . '/' . $fileName, 'r'));

$headers = new Headers();
$headers->addHeaders([
    'Content-Type' => [
        'application/force-download',
        'application/octet-stream',
        'application/download'
    ],
    'Content-Length' => filesize($path . '/' . $fileName),
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment;filename=' . $fileName,
    'Cache-Control' => 'must-revalidate',
    'Pragma' => 'no-cache',
    'Expires' => 'Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT'
]);

$response->setHeaders($headers);

$cookie = new SetCookie('downloadComplete', 'true', time() + 60 * 60, '/');
$response->getHeaders()->addHeader($cookie);

$response->setContent($writer);

return $response;
```

The problem is now that I only get a Zend error popup:

```
statusCode 200 thrownError SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 21 of the JSON data
```

And the content of my CSV as response text.

Do you have an idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you have CSV with invalid format, try to substitute another 100% valid CSV in generated file.

Comment: I have tried that approach already. I just found out that zend sends the wrong headers for the download if you post a request to the downloader. So via a direct download link the download works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of investigation I found out that the download only fails if we send a Post request to the download action via zend (I assume it overrides the self-setted headers). So I sendt the request via a java script redirect (`$viewModel->addScriptBlock('window.location = "Your URL";');`) and it worked.